# How can I add user input to an empty numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know how I should add user input to an empty numpy array. My original thinking was to use the insert function from numpy but I get the following error
"TypeError: _insert_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'"
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([])
put = input('what do you want to add to your array? Put it in a list: ')


class arr:
    def __init__(self, put, x):
        self.put = put
        self.x = x

    def putter(self):
        np.insert(x, put)
        print(x)

arg = arr(x, put)
arg.putter()
```

Comment: The best way to make an array is to collect the values in a list, and make the array from that.  The basic array constructor looks like `np.array([1,4,3,3 2])`.  Constructing an array (typically 100's of values) is impractical one `input` at a time.  More often the values are read from a file (`csv` format is common).

Comment: I think I will do that for my next project. I am just learning how to use numpy and want something small scale first. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy.append()

```
x = np.append(put, x)
```

Comment: When I put this in my code, I get two errors based on whether I put a single word/letter or if I put a list of words/ letters: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2' and UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I managed to solve the first issue which was  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2' . I still need help with the second one. If anybody could help me with that that would be great.

Comment: the first one means that you're not converting the input into integers. For the second one, I'm assuming you copy pasted that code exactly into the putter function... then you need to use self.x instead of x to update that variable.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I just learned how to use classes and I made a silly mistake.